# Split Double Values?

Tags: c#

i have two values written like this " +5.000" (first space then plus and the double value, double value is height in meters)

the first one is on textBox and second one is i'm receiving via ref key.

simply enough i want to get the result firstvalue - secondvalue = result

for example ( +5.000 -  +2.800 = 2.200)

result only in digits without plus.

i have asked this question also on c# forum 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a024e097-8013-4771-bbf6-99c7fd4cf457/double-split-

Thanks and Best Regards

Comment: Your question shows very little effort of you trying to solve the problem yourself. Please try to solve it yourself and if you get stuck then share with us what you've tried and where exactly you're getting stuck

Comment: Your `5.000` is `5` with decimal separator or `5000` with thousands separator?

Comment: Hello,I start it with my self and i'm trying it to myself also and a part that's not a very big, but i could't understand how can i get the correct anwser, please explain me how can i do math on one double and other string value. thay are written in same way ?? (first space then plus then double value. +5.000

Answer (score 1):

OK, I think you're trying to solve a few problems here in one question.  Let's break it down.

1. You need to get a value from a text box.  I'll assume its called txtBox in the absense of any code, so you need to write:

   ```
   double a = Double.parse(txtBox.Text);
   ```
2. You then need to perform your calculation.  This needs to be written the other way around, for example:

   ```
   result = a - b;
   ```

With limited source code it's difficult to answer properly.